# Failed 'atob' on 'Window': The string to be decoded is not correctly encoded.(error en atob() )

Tags: angular, jwt

#la encriptación del código se realiza satisfactoriamente pero cuando se quiere decodificar con atob me lanza error#
##cualquier ayuda se le agradece##

```
login(usuario: any): Observable<any> {

const urlEndpoint = 'http://localhost:8090/api/security/oauth/token';

const credentials = btoa('clienteapp:654321');//btoa() encriptar

const httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders({
  'Authorization': 'Basic ' + credentials,
  'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'

});

let params = new URLSearchParams();
params.set('username', usuario.userName);
params.set('password', usuario.userPassword);
params.set('grant_type', 'password');
console.log('parametros' + params.toString());
return this.http.post<any>(urlEndpoint, params.toString(), { headers: httpHeaders });
```

}

#los datos que se están enviando son datos normales no son con tildes u otro tipo de carácter que generan dos bytes probé algunos otros métodos pero aun no logro solucionarlo#

```
  getTokenData(accessToken: string): any {

    if (accessToken != '') {
      return JSON.parse(atob(accessToken.split(".")[1]));//error al decodificar
    }
    return null;
  }
```

[image: error ocurrido en la función atob]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

** bueno al parecer en mi caso la solución fue borrar el metodo JSON.parse la cual me lo estaba transformando a este tipo de dato [object object] y solo el metodo atob() sin nada lo desencripta y tiene la siguiente forma {"lastName":"admin","username":"admin","scope":["read","write"],"name":"juanito","userEmail":"juanito@juanito.com","exp":1617512547,"authorities":["ROLEADMIN"],"jti":"a02d992e-ba50-4d35-a9bf-8c7fe7261","clientid":"clienteapp"}**

```
  getTokenData(accessToken: string): any {
      if (accessToken != '') {
      return atob(accessToken.split(".")[1]);
    }
    console.log(console.log('getTokenData'));
    return null;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Haber prueba con este código.

```
  /**
   * 
   * @param utftext 
   * 
   * string =  cigueÃ±a nÃºmeros
   * La funcion decode(string) da como resultado cigueña números
   * 
   * 
   * 
   */
  decode(utftext) {
    var string = "";
    var i = 0;
    var c = 0;
    var c1 = 0;
    var c2 = 0;
    var c3 = 0;

    while (i < utftext.length) {

      c = utftext.charCodeAt(i);

      if (c < 128) {
        string += String.fromCharCode(c);
        i++;
      }
      else if ((c > 191) && (c < 224)) {
        c2 = utftext.charCodeAt(i + 1);
        string += String.fromCharCode(((c & 31) << 6) | (c2 & 63));
        i += 2;
      }
      else {
        c2 = utftext.charCodeAt(i + 1);
        c3 = utftext.charCodeAt(i + 2);
        string += String.fromCharCode(((c & 15) << 12) | ((c2 & 63) << 6) | (c3 & 63));
        i += 3;
      }

    }

    return string;
  }



  obtenerDatosToken(accessToken: string): any {

    // this.access_token = await this._storageService.cargarToken();

    if (accessToken != null) {

      return JSON.parse(this.decode(atob(accessToken.split('.')[1])));

    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }
```

Comment: gracias @Eloy Nuñez por tu aporte pero en mi caso la solución fue otra